# org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException

Tags: java, cxf, wsse

I am trying to connect with my client to my server and send a message which is encrypted and signed. I have checked all my configuration to make sure it is the same at both ends but I keep getting to following error. Any ideas of what I may be doing wrong. If you need anything else please tell me.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException.<init>(Lorg/apache/wss4j/common/ext/WSSecurityException$ErrorCode;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Exception;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V
org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandler.loadCallbackHandler(WSHandler.java:1169)
org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandler.getCallbackHandler(WSHandler.java:1127)
org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandler.getPasswordCallbackHandler(WSHandler.java:1141)
org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.getCallback(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:748)
org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.getCallback(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:728)
org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:241)
org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:190)
org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:96)
org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It seems that you're using library newer / older that does not have a particular method, OR your WSDL does not contain that method OR it has different signature.

Comment: It looks like you're using an incorrect version of WSS4J with CXF.

Comment: I am using wss4j 2.1.4 witch CXF 3.1.4